# Are there any Unicorns in Hogwarts Legacy?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I know in the first Harry Potter book, Voldemort uses Unicorn blood to sustain himself and keep himself alive. Later, Peter Pettigrew also uses Unicorn blood along with Nagini’s venom to create a potion that would create a temporary body for Voldemort.

I also know that some wands have Unicorn hair as the core.

But are there actual living Unicorn animals roaming around in the world of Hogwarts Legacy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**.

[image: Hogwarts Legacy - Unicorn info]

[image: Hogwarts Legacy - Shiny Unicorn]

### Where to find a Unicorn Den

You can find a Unicorn den in the Forbidden Forest. Head to the **East North Ford Bog Entrance Floo Flame** and go **south** to find the den. Keep in mind that this is the only Unicorn den in the game.

[image: Hogwarts Legacy - Unicorn Den]